Is 'intone' the right word for this?

"How did that happen!?"
"I miscalculated; overcharged the batteries."
"You overcharged the batteries?" Mr. B intoned.
"Yes."
"And the devices exploded; both of them?"
"Yes."

Is intoned the right word to use here to express the action of a flabbergasted Mr. B voicing out A's words to make sure he heard him correctly? If not, what verb should I use? Is it obvious what he is doing and how he is confused and surprised without the use of any action tags at all?

It's literary.  It's not to make sure he was heard correctly. He's repeating the first speaker's words, so "intoned" suggests those words are being spoken in a particular register or tone-of-voice either with artificial emotion, or totally devoid of emotion, deadpan.   We don't know the context or what "that" refers to in the first question.   How did you ruin your devices? How did you ruin the devices I lent you?

I would simply use repeated. Intoning is what the priest does in a formal church service.

I agree with Tim, and would add that it has a certain threat of authority to it (perhaps an overlap with Kate's priest example). It's something a headmaster can certainly do to a student he wants to intimidate.

That said, in this particular dialogue it's a little weird because the first line ends in an interrobang, whereas intoning implies a certain level of calm and control.

@KateBunting - In the Church of England, there are times when the worshippers intone back to the priest - Priest: O God, make speed to save us.
Answer. O Lord, make haste to help us.

And the priest's intoning can be either sing-song or in a droning monotone.

In churches in the US we are less formal, and say "Could you give us a hand, Lord,  ASAP?"

intoning just means serious without a change of intonation: it is in tone, get it? And it's fine here as a dialogue tag.

@TimR - In the UK we have the dignified churches that e.g. if Anglican follow the 1662  Book of Common Prayer, and also 'Happy Clappy' churches where the priest is called Pastor Jim, wears a pullover, plays guitar, starts prayers 'Hi, God!', and talks about 'my pal Jesus'.

@TimR - in the 1968 Lindsay Anderson film If, set in a boys' private school, the headmaster calls the assembled boys to prayer by intoning 'Let us praise Gurd'. It took me right back, as I attended a similar school, and one of my own classmates was an extra who spoke a few lines.

intone, snap, retort, gasp, snort, simper, sing out, shout out
These are called dialogue tags. There are many of them. Intone is possible, sure. The words in this answer are not a complete list.
Cambridge Dictionary:
intone
verb [ T ]   formal
us  /ɪnˈtoʊn/ uk  /ɪnˈtəʊn/
to say something slowly and seriously in a voice that does not rise or fall much:
[ + speech ] "Let us pray," the priest intoned to his congregation.
words used by authors in dialogues to describe attitude

What is a 'dialogue tag' (or speech tag)? Tags (like name tags)
identify.
In written conversation or a piece of dialogue, a tag is a group of
words following quoted speech (e.g. 'she said'). It identifies who
spoke and/or the tone or emotion behind their speech. Words for 'said'
may show or suggest:
Volume (e.g. yelled, shouted, bellowed, screamed, whispered)


Tone or pitch (e.g. shrieked, groaned, squeaked)


Emotion (e.g. grumbled,snapped, sneered, begged)


Intent (e.g. suggested, asked, demanded)


The connotations of dialogue tags are important. It would be strange,
for example, for a character to 'sneer' the words 'I love you', since
the word 'sneer' connotes contempt rather than affection. Unless their
words ran counter to how they truly felt. Even then, this would maybe
need additional, clarifying narration.

dialogue tags

Merriam-Webster: to utter in musical or prolonged tones : recite in singing tones or in a monotone. “Intone.” Merriam-Webster.com Dictionary, Merriam-Webster, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intone. Accessed 10 Dec. 2024.

@TimR recite in a monotone = to say something slowly and seriously in a voice that does not rise or fall much, which is why I didn't bother with M.W. They basically are saying the same thing.

But it can also be "in singing tones", which is rather the opposite of monotone, and there is a form of sarcastic repetition of what someone has just said that is rather sing-song in its delivery.

@TimR Either way, intoned can be used as a dialogue tag. That's my main point.

Yes, but the OP was asking if it was appropriate, not what academics call that sort of thing in a fiction. So I'm just making clear that it might be a monotone, or it might be more sing-song.

It sounds close to annoyance given the context and I think it's fine and not sing-songy.
